# Component with an impedance that has a negative real part

Tags: impedance, math

Is there an electrical component such that its impedance has a negative real part ?

**Fact:** Any electrical component made from resistors, inductances, capacitors (connected in possibly complex ways using series or parallel connections recursively) must have an impedance of a non-negative real part.

**Proof:** Suppose that there exists a way to connect the components (R,L,C) in a possibly complex ways using series or parallel connections recursively to get an impedance with a negative real part. Choose the connection of R,L,C that uses the **least** number of connecting wires. Let's call this component **COM**.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using simple devices L's, C's, and R's by themselves, you cannot get a negative resistance.  It takes either an active device (see Scott's answer) or some physics happening in an individual device.

There are at least three primary devices that hold historical significance that have this characteristic which are the Back diode, the Gunn diode and some tunnel diodes.

All of these devices have regions of their I-V curves that exhibit negative resistance.  You must bias the signal to span these regions of interest and not go beyond.
 Here is a snip from "American Micro Semiconductor

[image]

The back diode was used for envelope detection in early radar speed guns.

The Gunn diode operates on a different principale and is called a Transferred Electron Device (TED).  These are typically used in oscillators, when paralleled with a device of opposite characteristics the combination oscillates at millimeter wavelength frequencies.

Here is a semi-complete list of types of devices that all have negative resistance; (Source: - Complete guide to semiconductor devices by Kwok K. Ng);

- Tunnel type: Esaki Diode, Backward Diode, Back Diode.
- TED Type: Gunn Diode, Transferred electron Oscillator (TEO), TEA A=Amplifier.
- Resonant-Tunnelling type: Double barrier diode, RTFET.
- Resonant-interband tunnelling type.  Single barrier tunnel diode.Real-space transfer diode (RST).
- Metal insulator semiconductor switch type: MISS, MIS Thyristor (MIST) MEtal-Insulator-semiconductor-Metal (MISM) switch, Metal Insulator Semiconductor-Insulator Metal MISIM switch. Planar doped barrier switch (PDB), Double heterojunction optoelectronic switch (DOES)ledistor, Lasistor.
- Ammorphous Threshold Switch type: Ovonic threshold switch.  Heterostructure Hot-electron diode (HHED)

Answer (score 8):

Not with passives, so far as I know, but there are amplifiers you can build that have effectively negative input impedance, and they generally use positive feedback to achieve this.  For example, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_impedance_converter[image]

From the pointed-to wikipedia entry:

[image]

This example shows resistances, but R3, for example, can certainly be a capacitor.  The situation I've generally seen these used in are to cancel out the large impedances of glass microelectrodes that are pulled from pipettes, used to record neural signals

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will need some time to digest your answer as I am not an electrical/electronics engineer

Comment: Op amp circuits with "negative resistance" are also very common in motor-drive circuits (such circuits are referred to as "IR compensation"). One difficulty in using such circuits is that while one generally tries to make the controller's negative resistance balance out the motor's positive resistance (reducing the combined resistance toward zero will improve performance), motors behave very oddly if the combined resistance goes negative. A machine may sit still perfectly happily when nobody's pushing it, but trying to push the machine one way will make it move in the the other way.

Comment: Depending upon the nature of what's pushing the machine, this may be a "cute" behavior, or conceivably in some cases useful, but only if the total current fed to the motor is limited to a safe value.  Otherwise, if the machine encounters a fixed obstruction, the applied force will quickly rise to the machine's limit; if there were no limit, the force would rise infinitely until something moved or broke.

Comment: With electrode amplifiers, if you set the negative capacitance too big, the amp oscillates.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, as long as the negative slope of the current as a function of voltage curve is limited to the first and third quadrants.  Note that this is a necessity due to conservation of energy.  For operating points in the first and third quadrants, the device is dissipating power.  In the second and fourth quadrants, it is sourcing power.  A passive device, which implies no internal energy source, is therefore limited to operating in the first and third quadrants in steady state.

Some devices exhibit negative resistance over a part of their operating range.  It used to be popular to exploit this effect in unijunction transistors to make a single-transistor oscillator.

There are also devices that exhibit hysteresis, which you could consider negative resistance depending on how exactly you define that.  A neon bulb is a good example of a passive device with hysteresis that can be cycled many times.

To get sustained negative resistance over a wider operating range that might include the second and fourth quadrants requires a power source and therefore some active circuit.  You can make a point appear to have negative resistance to ground by using a opamp, for example.

As another example, the input to a ideal power supply exhibits negative resistance.  Since the power supply draws a fixed amount of power, the current it draws decreases with increasing voltage.  That is all limited to the first quadrant, but with our current technology requires a active circuit to realize.

Comment: Purely from an energy-conservation standpoint, it would be possible for a device to operate as a negative resistance provided there were an adequate external source of power (e.g. sufficient light shining on it).  From a control standpoint, however, I'm not sure how well one could make such a thing behave, since it would be inherently unstable.  I would expect it would be very hard not to have the behavior substantially controlled by non-linear phenomena.

Answer (score 2):

Negative real part of an impedance means that if you apply some voltage on the component, current flows in opposite direction. To specify, imagine some component with 2 pins A and B. When you connect B to GND and A to some positive voltage, if the DC current flows from B to A instead of A to B, that means that the real part of impedance has a negative value.

Unfortunately this isn't possible. Here is the explanation:

Current flow is the average electron flow on the line in basic level. Applying voltage means giving energy to system which makes electron move in one direction. If you observe that most of electrons flows in negative direction, it means that there is another independent power source inside the system which suppresses your outer power source.

Basically, if you don't have another power source in the system and calculate impedance value with negative real part, it conflicts with laws of thermodynamics.

Answer (score -1):

While it is true that you cannot connect the components (R,L,C) in a possibly complex ways using series or parallel connections recursively to get an impedance with a negative real part, the proof provided does not consider many circuits:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fRQHGZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Some circiuts do not consist of neither two impedances in series nor in parallel.